# Pass Parameter From OnClick Event from one Javascript Function to Another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a value from a hyperlink click from one JS function to another. In this context, I need the hyperlink text, which is a key from local storage. I need to pass that to a different html/JS script to access this key from local storage there. I'm having a hell of a time accomplishing this. The last console.log(); statement in this script returns "Link names: undefined"

```js
myApp.onPageInit("saved_locations", function(page) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var parent = document.getElementById("saved");
  var node;
  // iterate localStorage
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    // set iteration key name
    var key = localStorage.key(i);

    // use key name to retrieve the corresponding value
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    // console.log the iteration key and value
    console.log("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);

    let node = document.createElement("div");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.className = "link";
    a.textContent = key;
    a.style.color = "blue";
    a.href = "map_G.html";

    node.appendChild(a);

    fragment.appendChild(node);
  }

  parent.appendChild(fragment);

  var myForm = document.getElementById("enter_location");

  myForm.addEventListener("submit", function saveSearchLocation(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();

    var lat = document.getElementById("Latitude").value;
    var lon = document.getElementById("Longitude").value;
    var locationStr = document.getElementById("Location").value;

    //Save location parameters to local storage
    savedLocationParams = [lat, lon, locationStr];
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      locationStr,
      JSON.stringify(savedLocationParams)
    );
  });

  for (var i in document.getElementsByClassName("link")) {
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName("link")[i];

    link.onclick = function(e) {
      linkNames = e.srcElement.attributes.textContent;
      console.log("Link names: " + linkNames);
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pages">
    <div data-page="saved_locations" id="saved" class="page navbar-through no- 
    toolbar" align="center">
      <h2><br /><u>Enter A Location<br /><br /></u></h2>
      <form id="enter_location">
        Latitude: <input type="text" id="Latitude" value=""><br> Longitude: <input type="text" id="Longitude" value=""><br> Location: <input type="text" id="Location" value=""><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <h2><u>Saved Locations</u></h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: No, it's dynamic. User's can save locations in local storage, and this script creates hyperlink divs from each of those.

Comment: Will the text of the link ever change after it is created?

Comment: No. The text is the name of a location saved in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Since the link name doesn't change, just define the onclick function while you still have the key handy.

```
let a = document.createElement("a");
a.className = "link";
a.textContent = key;
a.style.color = "blue";
a.href = "map_G.html";

a.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("Link names: " + key);
};

node.appendChild(a);
```

At the bottom of this question is an MCVE of that solution.

Once you have it in the onclick, you could set another localstorage key that won't ever be a text of the link, something like "hambone_key" and set its value to the key you need to save, and then you can read "hambone_key" when you load up the page and get the key that way. E.g.,:

```
a.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("Link names: " + key);
  localStorage["hambone_key"] = key;
};
```

and then on page load:

```
var saved_key = localStorage.getItem("hambone_key");
if (saved_key === null) {
    // there is no saved key
} else { 
    // there is a saved key
    var important_value = localStorage.getItem(saved_key);

    // do stuff with important_value here
    // ....
}
```

**So, in the context of the code you have provided, it looks like this:**

```
myApp.onPageInit("saved_locations", function(page) {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  var parent = document.getElementById("saved");
  var node;
  // iterate localStorage
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    // set iteration key name
    var key = localStorage.key(i);

    // use key name to retrieve the corresponding value
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    // console.log the iteration key and value
    console.log("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);

    let node = document.createElement("div");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.className = "link";
    a.textContent = key;
    a.style.color = "blue";
    a.href = "map_G.html";

    a.onclick = function(e) {
      console.log("Link names: " + key);
      localStorage["hambone_key"] = key;
    };

    node.appendChild(a);

    fragment.appendChild(node);
  }

  parent.appendChild(fragment);

  var myForm = document.getElementById("enter_location");

  myForm.addEventListener("submit", function saveSearchLocation(event) {
    //event.preventDefault();

    var lat = document.getElementById("Latitude").value;
    var lon = document.getElementById("Longitude").value;
    var locationStr = document.getElementById("Location").value;

    //Save location parameters to local storage
    savedLocationParams = [lat, lon, locationStr];
    window.localStorage.setItem(
      locationStr,
      JSON.stringify(savedLocationParams)
    );
  });
});
```

And here is the MCVE of getting the key in the onclick function. The below code does not use localStorage here because it is forbidden in StackOverflow snippets:

```js
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var parent = document.getElementById("saved");
var node;
var fakeLocalStorage = {
  "key0": "value0",
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
};

// iterate localStorage
//for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  // set iteration key name
  //var key = localStorage.key(i);

  // use key name to retrieve the corresponding value
  //var value = localStorage[key];

  // set iteration key name
  let key = Object.keys(fakeLocalStorage)[i];

  // use key name to retrieve the corresponding value
  let value = fakeLocalStorage[key];

  // console.log the iteration key and value
  console.log("Key: " + key + ", Value: " + value);

  let node = document.createElement("div");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.className = "link";
  a.textContent = key;
  a.style.color = "blue";
  a.href = "javascript:return false;";

  a.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log("Link names: " + key);
  };

  node.appendChild(a);

  fragment.appendChild(node);
}

parent.appendChild(fragment);

var myForm = document.getElementById("enter_location");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", function saveSearchLocation(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();

  var lat = document.getElementById("Latitude").value;
  var lon = document.getElementById("Longitude").value;
  var locationStr = document.getElementById("Location").value;

  //Save location parameters to local storage
  savedLocationParams = [lat, lon, locationStr];
  window.localStorage.setItem(
    locationStr,
    JSON.stringify(savedLocationParams)
  );
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="pages">
    <div data-page="saved_locations" id="saved" class="page navbar-through no- 
    toolbar" align="center">
      <h2><br /><u>Enter A Location<br /><br /></u></h2>
      <form id="enter_location">
        Latitude: <input type="text" id="Latitude" value="">
        <br /> Longitude: <input type="text" id="Longitude" value="">
        <br /> Location: <input type="text" id="Location" value="">
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <h2><u>Saved Locations</u></h2>
    </div>
  </div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried putting a.onclick = function(e) {
  console.log("Link names: " + key);
}; where you suggested, and it always returns "Link names: undefined". Also, this edited HTML script doesn't work.

Comment: @BillHambone I fixed a bad console log. Are there any problems with it now?

Comment: I also removed a bad console.log();. With a.onclick = function(e) { console.log("Link names: " + key); }; where you suggested, it's returning the name of the last key in the list regardless of which one I click, probably because it's inside the loop. If I define a and key as global variables and move this click event outside of the loop, I can't even navigate to this page.

Comment: If you click `Run code snippet` at the bottom of this answer, it returns the name of the last key in the list?

Comment: No, I'm running it in Xcode simulator. I have ten different locations and it's returning the name of number ten, regardless of which one I click. I think it's because the onclick event is nested under the for loop that creates the links to begin with.

Comment: @BillHambone I edited my post to include a verbatim copy of your function with my code included. If that doesn't work, then you will need to edit your question and include your own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I recommend going to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/), creating your MCVE, and then editing your question to include a link to that MCVE.

Comment: @BillHambone Actually, I think I found the point of confusion. You put my code recommendation in the second loop you have, instead of getting rid of that second loop entirely and putting it in the link creation loop like in my example. See my edit.

Comment: Adding localStorage["hambone_key"] = key; to the a.onclick function prints out "Link names: hambone_key" and the hyperlinks no longer work. The problem is trying to grab the hyperlink key value inside the loop where the links are created. It's now defining 11 keys in the loop and only printing out the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution with JQuery:

```
$(a).click(function(e) {
          var txt = $(e.target).text();
          console.log("Link: " + txt)
          });
```